# Why is PWD empty and how to fix it?

Tags: c, cgi, lighttpd

I'm using lighttpd and wrote the following cgi script:

```
main(){
    printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
    char * pwd ="";
    pwd=getenv("PWD");
    printf ("The current path is: %s",pwd);
}
```

The Result is

```
The current path is: (null)
```

Well, I don't get why. And I don't know how to find the path of the script executed. I'm looking for args[0] with a path, and used pwd for that, but maybe I should switch to something different.

**UPDATE**

Not working aswell is

```
char cwd[_PC_PATH_MAX+1];
getcwd(cwd, _PC_PATH_MAX+1);
```

cwd is " ". Maybe my script knew where it was if I stoped using room 1408 as my datacenter. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `getcwd()` instead. `PWD` isn't required to be set.

```
#include <unistd.h>

char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size);
```

Answer (score 2):

`_PC_PATH_MAX` is not the max path length. It's a key you pass to `pathconf` to request the max path length, as in `pathconf("/", _PC_PATH_MAX)`. Of course if `PATH_MAX` is defined it would be simpler to use that directly.

Comment: Oh my... I know why scripting languages are so popular. That was it.